# How do I transpose every nth term in a list to a column from Pandas import?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I imported some data. And its just one line

```
 Jane  
 M  
 52,000 
 NYC 
 Mike  
 M  
 38,000 
 LA
```

AND so on I have 1000 lines

how do I get it to be

```
Name Sex salary City 
Jane  M  52,000 NYC 
Mike  M  38,000 LA
```

So every 5 lines make it a column I guess.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your output. From your inputs, looks like Mike's city is NYC and salary is 52k, but you put these values for Jane?

Comment: My apologies I corrected it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Simply `reshape`.

```
a = df['column_name'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 4)
```

Notice that `4` above means `4` columns, which looks like is what you have after your edit. Before, it looked like you had `5` columns. Just adapt to whatever you have

---

To make it a DataFrame

```
pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['Name', 'Sex', 'salary', 'City'])
```

---

Since your question is not well defined and it changed a lot after your edit, I hope the above can help being a lead on what you need

Comment: Great solution. Better than what I have, +1.

Comment: really sorry but I got KeyError: 'column_name'

Answer (score 0):

You need to grab every subseries of 5 elements (`iloc[]`), transform them ([`.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html)) and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) them.

```
data = pd.concat([df.iloc[s:s+4].reset_index(drop=True).T for s in range(0,len(df), 5)]).reset_index(drop=True)
data.columns = ['Name', 'Sex', 'City', 'Salary']
data['Sex'] = data['Sex'].str[0]
```

Output:

```
    Name    Sex     City    Salary
0   MiKE    M       NYC     52,000
1   MiKE    M       NYC     52,000
```

Comment: great thanks. One issue, not a big deal but it repeats after.